# jQuery select parent

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this html;

```
<div class="AttachmentContainer">
  <div class="display-label">Attachment name</div>
  <div class="display-field">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkAttachment" class="Attachment" /> 
    <%= thisAttachment.filename%>                                
  </div>
</div>
```

And on click of the checkbox i have this jQuery code;

```
$(this).parent(".AttachmentContainer").hide();
```

But it doesn't work.  If I alert out the html() instead of hide() it's null.

If I change it to;

```
$(this).parent().parent().hide();
```

it works fine.  I thought putting a selector on the parent would keep moving up until it found the parent with that class name.

I don't want to use `parent().parent()` so what else is there?

**edit**

`.parents("....` doesn't work either.

Comment: do you have multiple controls with `AttachmentContainer` class? If not, you could just use `$(".AttachmentContainer")`

Comment: Why don't you want to use parent().parent()? You want to affect the parent of the parent of the element you are in... parent().parent() seems perfect to me.

Comment: @patrick i just don't like it because if i add another level i need to remember to recode the jquery

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `closest` method to acheive this:

```
$(this).closest('.AttachmentContainer').hide();
```

Comment: +1 but I think I like parentsUntil a litte better and it works.  Yours does to btw and thanks.

Comment: Remember that parentsUntil includes "up to but not including the element matched by the selector".

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at **[parentsUntil](http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/)**